# Cannot run mysql stored procedure in laravel4

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, laravel

Have some php code:

```
    // Fetch PDO instance
    $pdo = $this->conn->getPdo();

    // Call procedure that checks is user credentials is ok
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('CALL Users_CheckLogin(:username, :password);');

    $passw = md5($credentials['passw']);

    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $credentials['username']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password', $passw);

    // Execute procedure
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'ArrayObject');
    $stmt->closeCursor();
```

For some reasons this code doesn't work here and returns:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

I also googled about this error and haven't found any fix for this. So perhaps someone here can explain me what the problem is? I don't have paralels queries, only my procedure, inside this procedure I executing additional queries so perhaps that a reason but then it is huge bug in pdo. This procedure call works in mysql manager and with mysqli also.

Comment: If you're using Laravel, why don't you try `Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));` to log in a user or `Auth::check();` to check if there is a logged in user? You can also hash your password use `$password = Hash::make('secret');`. Laravel 4 will do this for you via PDO.

Comment: Well,I change this by implementing my own Auth driver which implement laravel auth api and require some stored mysql procedures in my case.